# VB6 application causes install to show up

Tags: vb6, installation, openprocess

I got a weird problem with my VB app that has got me very confused.  I am updating an existing program.  I had to add some processing queue capabilities.  On my system, unit testing worked great but when I compile it and run it on a different computer (a network server machine) it first tries to open an office install.  If I cancel this, the program seems to run fine.  The problem is that this program will be run in the background and I can't be hitting cancel each time it runs.

So my question is this:  what is going on here?  I'm usually a java developer we eclipse so I'm used to being able to include all the needed libs into the jar files automatically.  It doesn't seem like the case with VB6.  it seems like it expects all the same libs to be on all the systems.  Is there any way to tell what might be triggering this?

The only thing I can think of that is causing it is that I'm using the "OpenProcess" function in the kernal32 lib.  that the only major change I have made.

any help would be very appricated.  thanks!

EDIT:
It seems that multiple versions of word were installed on the system and it was screwing things up somehow.  We uninstalled one and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this a while ago and it was related to my installer for the VB6 app overwriting some system files for Office that it shouldn't have.  Any time one of the System dlls was accessed Windows would determine that something was wrong and the Office installer would start up.

The short-term fix was to let the Office Installer repair the broken chain of dlls.

The long-term fix was to never overwrite built-in Windows System dlls.

You could also check out the [Microsoft Fix it Center](http://support.microsoft.com/fixit/).